# OpenCV: Using Sobel operator: dx=1, dy=0 gives exactly same output as dx=0, dy=1 (bug?)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

This piece of code seems to be generating exactly same Sobel gradients for dx=1, dy=0 and dx=0, dy=1.
This means I can't subtract `gradY` from `gradX` because that leaves me with a black image.

Is this a bug in OpenCV? Is the code wrong?

The input image is an image captured from the smartphone's camera.

```
Mat gradX = new Mat();
Mat gradY = new Mat();
Mat gray = new Mat();
Mat gradient = new Mat()

Imgproc.cvtColor( cameraSnapshotFrame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

Imgproc.Sobel( gray, gradX, CV_32F, 1, 0, -1, 1.0, 0 );
Imgproc.Sobel( gray, gradY, CV_32F, 0, 1, -1, 1.0, 0 ); // for some reason this gives the same result as the line above

Core.subtract( gradX, gradY, gradient );
Core.convertScaleAbs( gradient, gradient ); // gradient is an empty black image
```

I am using OpenCV for Android version 3.1.0.

Comment: Kernel size = -1? That doesn't seem right

Comment: According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d) a value of `ksize = -1` will use a Scharr filter. Using other values of `ksize` doesn't seem to matter though; the X and Y gradients are always identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue.

The OpenCV library can be used in two ways on an Android smartphone: it can be embedded within an application directly, or installed as an app - "OpenCV Manager", which then provides the libraries to the OpenCV apps dynamically.

My application was using the OpenCV Manager app to get the libraries. Unfortunately, it appears that OpenCV Manager for Android is bugged, because when I embedded the OpenCV library directly within my app, the Sobel calls started working properly.

So I recommend everyone to link their applications to OpenCV statically.